# Sympy algebraic solution to series summation

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve for `C` in the following equation

[image]

I can do this with `sympy` for an enumrated number of `x's`, e.g `x0, x2, ..., x4` but cannot seem to figure out how to do this for `i=0` to `t`. E.g. for a limited number

```
from sympy import summation, symbols, solve

x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, alpha, C = symbols('x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, alpha, C')

e1 = ((x0 + alpha * x1 + alpha**(2) * x2 + alpha**(3) * x3 + alpha**(4) * x4)
      / (1 + alpha + alpha**(2) + alpha**(3) + alpha**(4)))
e2 = (x3 + alpha * x4) / (1 + alpha)
rhs = (x0 + alpha * x1 + alpha**(2) * x2)  / (1 + alpha + alpha**(2))

soln_C = solve(e1 - C*e2 - rhs, C)
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've never used this module personally, but [this](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html) suggests you can use the `Sum(..)` function (scroll down to Finite Sums).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @bryans for pointing me in the direction of `Sum`. Elaborating on his comment, here is one solution that seems to work. As I am fairly new to `sympy` if anyone has a more concise approach please share.

```
from sympy import summation, symbols, solve, Function, Sum

alpha, C, t, i = symbols('alpha, C, t, i')
x = Function('x')

s1 = Sum(alpha**i * x(t-i), (i, 0, t)) / Sum(alpha**i, (i, 0, t))
s2 = Sum(alpha**i * x(t-3-i), (i, 0, t-3)) / Sum(alpha**i, (i, 0, t-3)) 
rhs = (x(0) + alpha * x(1) + alpha**(2) * x(2))  / (1 + alpha + alpha**(2))
```

[image]

```
soln_C = solve(s1 - C*s2 - rhs, C)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be catalogued as more *"concise"*, but it could be useful too, when you know the upper limit of the summatory. Let's suppose that we want to evaluate this expression:

[image]

We can express it, and solve it, in sympy as follows:

```
from sympy import init_session
init_session(use_latex=True)
n = 4
As = symbols('A_1:' + str(n+1))
x = symbols('x')
exp = 0
for i in range(n):
    exp += As[i]/(1+x)**(i+1)
Ec = Eq(exp,0)
sol = solve(Ec,x)
#print(sol)
#sol    #Or, if you're working on jupyter...
```